# TinyMCE Spellchecker returns "Current spellchecker isn't supported"

Tags: php, tinymce, spell-checking

After trying to check my spelling spellchecker.php returns an error - "Current spellchecker isn't supported." ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS67c.png)). PHPinfo shows that "Enchant" module exists on the server.

If I switch spell checking engine to the "pspell" (which is also on the server) then spellchecker.php returns the same incorrect word and nothing else
([the screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zf4Il.png))
Also there is an error: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: PSpell.mode"

I just migrated to a new web server and I guess that there might be some problems with pspell or enchant versions.

Comment: Can you tell us the specific version of TinyMCE you are using? Also, can you post your tinymce.init() configuration?

Comment: I'am using version 4.6.1 and my tinymce.init() looks like this: https://imgur.com/ovaGG7g